# Using webview in tab bar application

Tags: ios, objective-c, webview

I am using this code to load html content in webview

```
    - (void)viewDidLoad {
        [super viewDidLoad];

        NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle]pathForResource:@"about.html" ofType:nil]];
        NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
        [webView loadRequest:request];


    }
```

When AboutViewController tab(featured) is selected .Program shows blank screen does loads any kind of html content .
The sample program is given on following link .https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B5pNDpbvZ8SnbEhzMFFTNXJDXzA
Why code is not loading html ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reviewing your project, your code is fine but the real problem is that your AboutViewController viewDidLoad is not called, you must change the segue type of your NavigationController from push to rootViewController, to you AboutViewController and start working as should

**Edited Code**

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    NSString *pathString = [[NSBundle mainBundle]pathForResource:@"about.html" ofType:nil];
    if(pathString)
    {
        NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:pathString];
        if(url)
        {
            NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
            [webView loadRequest:request];
        }
        NSLog(@"%@", url.description);
    }
    NSLog(@"%@", pathString);

}
```

**WAS**

[image]

**SHOULD BE**

[image]

**RESULT**

[image]

Hope this helps you

Comment: still code is showing blank screen and not loading html .

Comment: I am reviewing it, this code is from other project and works, so maybe the problem is some other part, as soon as I found something i will update my answer

Comment: @user2557829 Reviewing your project, your `AboutViewController` viewDidLoad is not called, you must change the segue type of your NavigationController from push to rootViewController, to you AboutViewController and start working as should

Comment: @user2557829 Review my answer again was edited!, hope helps you

Comment: Now it is loading the AboutViewController.but not showing about.html

Comment: @user2557829 your code is fine, the other thing i did was remove the about.html and was added again and also added the image in the project, must work

Comment: I have selected rootViewController instead of push segue. if featured tab bar is selected  program is crashing on "Thread signal SIGABRT" .it is not loading AboutViewController.From this link you can check this error .https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B5pNDpbvZ8SnYlJfZGtaX1k1Zk0

Comment: @user2557829 the problem is related to your resource file about.html, when I open your project don't compile for me, i have to remove the about.html and add it again to the project, this is the issue you are facing, please let me know if the crash is this `2017-07-09 19:43:44.967 webviewapp[13692:1371225] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** -[NSURL initFileURLWithPath:]: nil string parameter'`

Comment: @user2557829 my answer was edited with improved code to avoid the crash, if NSLog prints `2017-07-09 19:57:06.244 webviewapp[13949:1378557] (null)`  this is because your resource about.html was not added correctly in your project